# How to control access of models in RStudio Connect?

Tags: rstudio

Models running in RStudio Connect run with the privileges of the unix account that runs the RStudio Connect application. Is it possible to make sure some models have one set of privileges so that they can access certain files and another set of models have other privileges?

Comment: session$user gives you the account of the user. With this information you can control your models.

Comment: @Florian this would mean the model will still run with the privileges of the service account that is running RConnect. The model will have to implement code to check for the $user and take decisions accordingly.  I would rather prefer letting the model run as a certain unix user so that the model has only the rights that the unix user has. Can the code that checks the $user change the user that runs the model?